# How to use GAMs to test whether a prediction model is properly calibrated in R

Tags: r, anova, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model, calibration

Suppose we wish to test whether there is an identity relationship between some observed values and the predicted values from some model, and allow for non-linear deviations from this hypothesis. This is a test for model calibration, or whether predicted values resemble the observed values. Thus we test
$$H_0 : \text{model is calibrated}$$
against
$$H_A : \text{model is not calibrated}.$$

I am using **mgcv** to conduct such a test; under the null hypothesis, the best-fitting model for the relationship between the observed and predicted data is the identity relationship (the line $\text{observed} = \text{predicted}$). If a fit other than the identity line better describes the relationship between observed and predicted values, we should reject the null hypothesis. This other relationship is allowed to be any (smooth) relationship, hence the use of generalized additive models. Thus, one should compare a GAM with an intercept and a smooth function of the predicted values to a "model" with a linear identity relationship, which can be done using something resembling ANOVA for GAMs.

Below is R code demonstrating this idea. First is the data.

```
# NECESSARY DATA --------------------------------------------------------------
# CONTINUOUS ------------------------------------------------------------------
func_train <- structure(list(t = c(0.0303030303030303, 0.0404040404040404,
0.0505050505050505, 0.0606060606060606, 0.0707070707070707, 0.0808080808080808,
0.121212121212121, 0.131313131313131, 0.151515151515152, 0.171717171717172,
0.181818181818182, 0.212121212121212, 0.222222222222222, 0.232323232323232,
0.242424242424242, 0.252525252525253, 0.272727272727273, 0.282828282828283,
0.292929292929293, 0.313131313131313, 0.323232323232323, 0.333333333333333,
0.343434343434343, 0.383838383838384, 0.414141414141414, 0.434343434343434,
0.444444444444444, 0.464646464646465, 0.474747474747475, 0.494949494949495,
0.525252525252525, 0.535353535353535, 0.585858585858586, 0.636363636363636,
0.656565656565657, 0.666666666666667, 0.686868686868687, 0.707070707070707,
0.737373737373737, 0.747474747474748, 0.757575757575758, 0.767676767676768,
0.787878787878788, 0.797979797979798, 0.808080808080808, 0.838383838383838,
0.858585858585859, 0.878787878787879, 0.939393939393939, 0.94949494949495,
0.95959595959596, 0.97979797979798), xt = c(3.63646184859767,
2.04366285020827, 2.40217293175171, 1.92764066195575, 2.09648921296279,
1.83178201173648, 2.59777911981743, 1.70198152297048, 3.1380721870924,
2.71868172485417, 3.38388214151374, 2.42085094978724, 2.56497719313567,
3.44671977084476, 2.39025018974132, 1.48377974658384, 3.18324259582037,
2.67374271529648, 2.43479989087673, 2.94967229684157, 3.72188635380589,
1.96556247970551, 2.51248175746488, 2.30538233637176, 2.53759710325252,
0.929349103723103, 1.06886278854257, 1.61838423274164, 0.671269406607747,
1.43763814664885, 1.9223411940236, 1.3614459122771, 1.38318561351847,
1.69640947189312, 1.5065339734596, 1.98566063977038, 0.666709569418715,
0.98379114909344, 1.57865628080262, 2.07604740761617, 2.24889414005422,
3.55793900242699, 2.42813714143812, 3.47050731227238, 2.09330094819542,
2.88930885347281, 4.12094951149849, 3.3426038340013, 3.89767608248133,
4.04384524659107, 4.39797282760465, 3.95885899856536)), row.names = c(4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L,
26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 39L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 47L,
48L, 50L, 53L, 54L, 59L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 74L, 75L, 76L,
77L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 84L, 86L, 88L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 98L), class = "data.frame")

# BINARY ----------------------------------------------------------------------
inv_logit <- \(z) exp(z)/(1 + exp(z))
new_t <- seq(-2, 2, length = 100)
train_bin_t <- tibble(t = new_t, pass = inv_logit(new_t ^ 2 - 2) %>%
  map_int(~ rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = .x)))
test_bin_t <- tibble(t = new_t, pass = inv_logit(new_t ^ 2 - 2) %>%
  map_int(~ rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = .x)))
```

Next, the procedure:

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

func_gam_cont_overfit <- gam(xt ~ s(t), data = func_train, family = gaussian,
                             sp = 1e-4)
func_gam_bin <- gam(pass ~ s(t), data = train_bin_t, family = binomial)

calib_fit <- function(observed, predicted, ...) {
  calib_df <- tibble(observed = observed, predicted = predicted)
  calib_gam <- gam(observed ~ offset(predicted) + s(predicted, m = c(2, 0)),
                  data = calib_df, ...)
  null_fit <- gam(observed ~ offset(predicted) - a, data = calib_df, ...)
  make_fit_df <- function(d) {
             pred <- seq(min(d$predicted), max(d$predicted), length = 100)
             tibble(predicted = pred) %>%
             cbind(as_tibble(predict(calib_gam, .,
                                     type = "response",
                                     se.fit = TRUE))) %>%
             rename(observed = fit)}
  list(calib_gam = calib_gam,
       null_fit = null_fit,
       calib_viz = ggplot(calib_df, aes(x = predicted, y = observed)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_line(data = make_fit_df, aes(x = predicted,
                                           y = observed),
                   color = "red") +
         geom_ribbon(data = make_fit_df, aes(x = predicted,
                                             ymin = observed - 2 * se.fit,
                                             ymax = observed + 2 * se.fit),
                     fill = "pink", alpha = 0.5) +
         geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, color = "blue"))
}

# INITIAL CALIBRATION FIT AND PLOTS -------------------------------------------

axis_lim <- c(0.5, 5)

is_cont_obs_calib <- calib_fit(func_train$xt, predict(func_gam_cont_overfit,
                                                  func_train["t"],
                                                  type = "response"))
is_cont_obs_calib_plot <- is_cont_obs_calib$calib_viz +
  coord_cartesian(axis_lim, axis_lim) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Continuous")

is_bin_obs_calib <- calib_fit(train_bin_t$pass, predict(func_gam_bin,
                                                    test_bin_t["t"],
                                                    type = "response"),
                          family = binomial)
is_bin_obs_calib_plot <- is_bin_obs_calib$calib_viz +
  coord_cartesian(0:1, 0:1) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Binary")

is_cont_obs_calib_plot | is_bin_obs_calib_plot

# TESTS FOR CALIBRATION -------------------------------------------------------
summary(is_cont_obs_calib$calib_gam)  # Note p-value for intercept and smooth
summary(is_bin_obs_calib$calib_gam)

with(is_cont_obs_calib, anova(calib_gam, null_fit, test = "Chisq"))  # Note p-value
with(is_bin_obs_calib, anova(calib_gam, null_fit, test = "Chisq"))
```

Output is below.

[image: Calibration plots]

```
Family: gaussian
Link function: identity

Formula:
observed ~ offset(predicted) + s(predicted, m = c(2, 0))

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2.990e-14  7.691e-02       0        1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                   edf Ref.df F p-value
s(predicted) 2.648e-10      8 0   0.957

R-sq.(adj) =  0.655   Deviance explained = 5.66e-11%
GCV = 0.31364  Scale est. = 0.30761   n = 52

Family: binomial
Link function: logit

Formula:
observed ~ offset(predicted) + s(predicted, m = c(2, 0))

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -0.8927     0.2375  -3.759 0.000171 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
               edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value
s(predicted) 1.522      8  15.28 4.44e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.28   Deviance explained =   16%
UBRE = 0.086762  Scale est. = 1         n = 100
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: observed ~ offset(predicted) + s(predicted, m = c(2, 0))
Model 2: observed ~ offset(predicted) - a
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev         Df    Deviance  Pr(>Chi)
1        51     15.688
2        51     15.688 -5.297e-10 -8.8871e-12 6.458e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: observed ~ offset(predicted) + s(predicted, m = c(2, 0))
Model 2: observed ~ offset(predicted) - a
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev      Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)
1    96.998     103.63
2    99.000     123.44 -2.0021  -19.808 5.013e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

In particular, notice the result for the continuous case in the example. Why does the ANOVA test reject when neither the smooth nor the slope are anywhere near significant? I know these tests are allowed to disagree, but the difference here is so stark that I'm suspicious that I'm doing the ANOVA procedure wrong. Is using ANOVA this way allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. Remove the null space requirements from the fit. As described in the documentation of **mgcv** (man, it's so good), p-value approximations are terrible with there being no null space. So in the function, change the computation of `calib_gam`.

```
  calib_gam <- gam(observed ~ s(predicted),
                   data = calib_df, ...)
```